# What Bitcoin profitability calculators account for taxation on miner income?

Tags: legal, taxes, mining-profitability

If I were to run a miner, I want to be ethical and pay all relevant income tax and gain all required licensing, etc for my country.

My miner income is probably taxed at a 1099 income rate or lower, but to be less region-specific, a calculator could potentially account for hardware (and other) costs and also allow the user to specify tax rates.

What profitability calculators take this into account?

Comment: Are these questions real questions you have or are you trying to make an argument that it is unfair that people can mine at a profit and the state likely not being able to know about any of that income?

Comment: I voted to close this one as well.

Comment: @StephenGornick I have no argument to make other than miners (and anyone else part of the Bitcoin system) will likely have fewer legal headaches if they pay taxes.  Your downvotes on all my questions and close votes are not constructive for rational and open discourse.

Comment: Reworded to make this less region-specific. Maybe it's worth keeping open now?

Answer (score 2):

None do now and none likely will anytime soon.

This will vary per-tax jurisdiction and per individual circumstances because income taxes are based on profit not on revenue.

This is the very first inquiry I've seen where this feature has been requested, incidentally.